# How do I calculate posterior probabilities from the results of linear discriminant analysis in Accord.NET?

Tags: c#, r, probability, accord.net, linear-discriminant

I am currently porting an image processing project from R to C#. At the end of the pipeline there is a binary classifier for which I have used linear discriminant analysis as the input vector consists just of two doubles. In R I have used the `lda` function from the MASS package, in C# I am using `LinearDiscriminantAnalysis` class from Accord.NET. The classifier itself works just fine, but apart from the prediction itself I also have to extract a probability or confidence. In MASS posterior probabilities are conveniently part of the return value of the `predict.lda` function, but in Accord.NET there seems to be no easy way to get probabilities. I have tried computing probabilities from the result of the `Scores` method in the `LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.Pipeline` class using the softmax function, but since the scores are in the range between -0.01 and -0.08 the probabilities hover around 50%, which is out of line with the results I get in R and with the fact that the separation achieved with the classifier is excellent. Is there a simple way of computing the posterior probabilities I get in R from the output of the `LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.Pipeline` classifier?

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code you've attempted (including listing non-base R packages, and any errors/warnings received), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))` into a [code block]), and intended output given that input. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Interesting question, however, it's off topic here since it's more conceptual; stats.stackexchange.com is more suitable. That said, my advice is to swap out the LDA and construct a logistic regression instead. A LR with a specified threshold for the output score is equivalent to an LDA -- positive and negative examples are divided by a plane -- with the additional benefit that the LR scores are in fact posterior class probabilities, p(c | x) where c is the class and x is the input vector. You can try to reverse engineer a posterior probability via distance from x to the class boundary plane,

Comment: and it sounds like maybe you're doing something like that already, but that's just replicating the work done by the LR. My advice is don't try to smash a square peg into a round hole, just put aside the LDA and go ahead with LR. Incidentally plugging in LR also makes it easier to substitute, at some future time, other classification models such as neural networks, since those also produce posterior class probabilities.